# CodeLite formatting

Tags: c++, codelite

I use the [CodeLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeLite) IDE for C++ development, but I have not found any way to select -> format the text properly.

This:

```
if(1 == 1){
return 1;
}
```

should be formatted as:

```
if(1 == 1){
   return 1;
}
```

Is there a way to select a block of code and then format it using the CodeLite IDE?

Answer (score 24):

Go to menu *Plugins* → *Source Code Formatter* → *Format Current Source* or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

If you want to set up your formatting preferences, choose menu *Plugins* → *Source Code Formatter* → *Options...*